# How can I change the format of relative numbers?

Tags: line-numbers

I use this plugin relative-line-numbers of Fanael on Github.
how to add extra spaces on the both sides of the relative number sides?

Form this

[image]

To this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> **relative-line-numbers-format** is a variable defined in
>   **‘relative-line-numbers.el’**. Its value is
>   **relative-line-numbers-default-format**
>
> Documentation:
>   The function used to format the line numbers. The function should take
>   one integer argument: the line’s distance, in lines, from the current
>   line, and return a string.
>
> You can customize this variable.

You will have first to define somewhere in your configuration file, a function to use for formatting, for example:

```el
(defun my-relative-line-numbers-default-format (offset)
  "The default formatting function.                                                                                        
Return the absolute value of OFFSET, converted to string."
  (concat " - " (number-to-string (abs offset)) " + "))
```

Then, you will have to call `M-x customize-variable` then type `relative-line-numbers-format`. You'll be shown a window inside with you can change the name of the function used for formatting, use your custom function defined above. Then you'll have to apply and save.